# SharePoint 2013 List Permission issue with root list and subsite list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, lookup-column, sub-site

I have an issue with SharePoint (Office 365) can you help out to solve my issue.

I have a list with confidential data in root site and I have subsite with a list that is referring some column(lookup field) from root site.

So my issue is few user are not having access(as I am having confidential data in the list) to root list but I need those users to access the subsite list, but now they are not able to access the subsite itself as they don't have access to the root site.

Please help me with this...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, some users that have permissions to sub-site, cannot open sub-site list and you want them to be able to see sub-site list? If that is the case, you have to give them at least read permissions to list from where lookup column is taking information.

Comment: But if I am giving read permission they will be able to read/view other columns(Confidential data)/site in root site. That should not happen, How can I overcome from this issue ?

Comment: If you want with lookup to do it, you have to give them Read permissions at least on list on root site.

Comment: But the issue is they will be able to read/view other columns(confidential information) as well.